# GTK3+ - How to update graphics based on mouse click?

Tags: c, gtk3, cairo

I am trying to modify the cairo graphics rendering I found in http://zetcode.com/gfx/cairo/basicdrawing/ so that it updates the graphics when I click the drawing area with the left mouse button. Currently the code in the website uses the right mouse button click to update the graphics.

I have tried adding **gtk_widget_queue_draw(widget);** to **gboolean clicked()**, when **event->button == 1**:

```
#include <cairo.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static void do_drawing(cairo_t *);

struct {
  int count;
  double coordx[100];
  double coordy[100];
} glob;

static gboolean on_draw_event(GtkWidget *widget, cairo_t *cr, 
    gpointer user_data)
{
  do_drawing(cr);

  return FALSE;
}

static void do_drawing(cairo_t *cr)
{
  cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, 0, 0, 0);
  cairo_set_line_width(cr, 0.5);

  int i, j;
  for (i = 0; i <= glob.count - 1; i++ ) {
      for (j = 0; j <= glob.count - 1; j++ ) {
          cairo_move_to(cr, glob.coordx[i], glob.coordy[i]);
          cairo_line_to(cr, glob.coordx[j], glob.coordy[j]);
      }
  }

  glob.count = 0;
  cairo_stroke(cr);    
}

static gboolean clicked(GtkWidget *widget, GdkEventButton *event,
    gpointer user_data)
{
    if (event->button == 1) {
        glob.coordx[glob.count] = event->x;
        glob.coordy[glob.count++] = event->y;
        gtk_widget_queue_draw(widget);
    }

    if (event->button == 3) {
        gtk_widget_queue_draw(widget);
    }

    return TRUE;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  GtkWidget *window;
  GtkWidget *darea;

  glob.count = 0;

  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

  window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);

  darea = gtk_drawing_area_new();
  gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), darea);

  gtk_widget_add_events(window, GDK_BUTTON_PRESS_MASK);

  g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(darea), "draw", 
      G_CALLBACK(on_draw_event), NULL); 
  g_signal_connect(window, "destroy",
      G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);  

  g_signal_connect(window, "button-press-event", 
      G_CALLBACK(clicked), NULL);

  gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);
  gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 400, 300); 
  gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "Lines");

  gtk_widget_show_all(window);

  gtk_main();

  return 0;
}
```

However, this does not work since now the graphics aren't updated at all.

Is there a way of updating the graphics by pressing the left mouse button (button 1) and simultaneously carry out inserting the coordinates to struct **glob** as before?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting `glob.count = 0` after drawing the lines, however `glob.count` is only updated by one in the `clicked()` callback, so it will never draw more than a single line. Also the first line is from point `(glob.coordx[0], glob.coordy[0])` to `(glob.coordx[0], glob.coordy[0])` (that is: it starts and ends at the same point) so it has no length, and will not be visible.

Solution: remove the line `glob.count = 0;` from `do_drawing()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
g_signal_connect(window, "button-press-event", G_CALLBACK(clicked), NULL);
```

When your callback is called, the `window` (which emits `"button-press-event"`) is passed as first parameter. The `queue_draw` call queues redraw of window. However, redraw  of `DrawingArea` is not requested and will not happen.

You can:

1. Queue redraw of `DrawingArea`
2. Connect to `"button-press-event"` of `DrawingArea`
3. Without any changes of code: press a mouse button and resize the window. Gtk will see, that `DrawingArea` has changed (it's resized too) and queue redraw of this widget.

Comment: I tried to add **g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(darea), "draw", G_CALLBACK(clicked), NULL);**, but it still does not work!

Comment: @0x76syoa8p you may need to `gtk_widget_add_events(darea, GDK_BUTTON_PRESS_MASK);
`